# Adding a system tray icon to a Chrome App like the Google Hangouts app does?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, system-tray

The [Google Hangouts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) Chrome App adds itself to the system tray

[image: Google Hangouts in system tray]

I cannot find any documentation on how this is done. Is this a special thing only Google can do, or is this possible? How?

Comment: Feel free to mark this question as a duplicate of that.